# How can I use 1 GPIO output signal to trigger 4 external pins in a staggered manner?

Tags: signal, multiplexer, gpio

I am looking to send the same signal (for example send HIGH, 3V) from a GPIO pin to 4 receiving devices in a staggered manner; it is important that the signal arrives at different times (short delay).

I only have 2 GPIO pins available on my board. There is an option to potentially use a demultiplexer that could work.

I still potentially have an issue with the propagation delay here, so any suggestions as to how to increase that delay would be appreciated.

Does anyone have any potentially alternatives to a demultiplexer?

Comment: Use a GPIO expander that has an I2C interface? Something like [MCP23017](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/mcp23017).

Comment: A shift register like 74hc164 with 2 pins for clock and data.

Comment: *There is an option to potentially use a demultiplexer that could work.* <-- please show that circuit so that functionality is confirmed.

Comment: @Andyaka the demultiplexer circuit would be easy simply because the enable pin would either be high or low, a gpio pin and ground, with the 4 outputs connected to my receiving devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this might work for your purpose, depending on what you think *short delay* means and how tolerant you need it to be with regards to temperature and component variation.

Each output is delayed through an [RC filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC_time_constant) and a [Schmitt trigger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schmitt_trigger), causing a digital delay based on the RC time. The Schmitt trigger is typically a single component with multiple gates, such as the 74HC14 (inverter, but just invert it in the MCU).

Each output can have a unique delay based on the values for R and C.

[image: Schematic capture of RC filter delay]

[image: Graph of the output]

Comment: I like this idea, it's simple. You could even cascade the components [like this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8XwA.png) to ensure a well defined order with regards to temperature and component variation.

Comment: @Velvel Yeah, I thought about that _after_ I finished making the graphics for this answer, and couldn't bother to update it. But I think cascading is better, especially if the delay is the same.